# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist using iBatis

Tags: oracle, mybatis, synonym

**I am using MyBatis 3 to create a request (seen below) however, I am getting:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
where SYNONYM_A is a public Synonym for a table in another database...**

*I know the example doesn't really help, but the real question is, "Is there a special syntax for synonyms in Batis?"  Has anyone done this, or failed, and can tell me, so I don't spend a great deal of effort, if it is not valid in Batis?*

@Select("select * from SYNONYM_A where some_det_key in (SELECT DATA_KEY FROM SOME_PARENT_TABLE  WHERE PARENT_KEY = 1234 AND (ATTACH_PARENT_FLG = 1 or ATTACH_PARENT_FLG is null) AND DATA_SRC = 'LV_SOME_DET') ORDER BY pair

Comment: What if you run the query directly from sqlplus, and the same db user.  Is there a db link setup?  Are all grants correct?

Comment: Yes, this does work from sqlplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is....

I was connected to the wrong database instance!!  I had built extended  AbstractRoutingDataSource, and was pulling the server name for the datasource from a primary database.  I discovered that another individual had populated this table incorrectly, and pointed me to a database where the synonym did not exist.

Thank you for your responses, and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the select grant FROM the PARENT schema to the current schema once again for the table of which SYNONYM_A is a synonym of.

And is SYNONYM_A  a synonym for a Table or a synonym of another SYNONYM in the PARENT schema?
In case it is, u need to provide grant from the ultimate base schema where the actual table is located once again 'WITH GRANT OPTION'

Comment: Did I mention that SYNONYM_A is a public synonym?  Doesn't that mean that the grants are not required, because it is available to everyone? --  I have tested this in SQLPLUS for multiple users, and they all succeed...

Comment: SYNONYM_A is defined as
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM "SYNONYM_A" FOR "SOME_TABLE"@"CONNECTION_TO_ANOTHER_DATABASE";

Comment: Synonyms and grants are two different objects.  synonym is a namespace issue.

Answer (score 0):

A public synonym does not mean that grants are not required from the schema in which the parent table lies(if the synonym and the table lies in two different schemas, that is). You need to clarify your concept of public synonyms :) .

But thats not the point here.
just do:

```
SELECT * SOME_TABLE"@"CONNECTION_TO_ANOTHER_DATABASE;
```

If this gives you ORA-XXXX: Table or view doesnot exist, then this is the cause.

There are two possibilities:

1.CONNECTION_TO_ANOTHER_DATABASE has got corrupted/doesnot exist.
  You can check this by doing queries like :

```
Select sysdate from duals@CONNECTION_TO_ANOTHER_DATABASE;
Select * from user_objects@CONNECTION_TO_ANOTHER_DATABASE;
```

If this too gives you the same error then that's it, your CONNECTION_TO_ANOTHER_DATABASE is gone.

If this does not give any error and gives some valid o/p then:

2.Probably the "SOME_TABLE" at the remote database does not exist!

Comment: But, as I said to "OldProgrammer", the statement works in SQLPLUS, but does not work in JDBC through MyBatis.  I have checked the connection, and it is the same database/user/password, for both, as I log these out...  I was simply wondering if there is an issue with either Batis, or JDBC in reference to Synonyms.